# Getting the ID's of all selected field in php

Tags: php, mysql

When i select multiple checkbox, i get the values something like this....

```
9,admin@domain.com,1,9,gg@domain.com,2,2,pra@domain.com,3,2,sh@sh.com,4
```

Now i need to delete all of them, so i need to pass their user ID alone to query. For this i need to split the string and pass their multiple ID's alone to query.

```
    $var1 = $theArrayValue;
$chan= explode(',', $var1);
return $chan;
```

$theArrayValue holds all these info below.

```
9,admin@domain.com,1,9,gg@domain.com,2,2,pra@domain.com,3,2,sh@sh.com,4
```

**I need to delete multiple items selected.**

Comment: And what is the actual question? You should at least post what the expected result is.

Comment: Let's see the form you're parsing, as well.  My guess is you'll need to use [] at the end of your field names, and then you can simply use the array_unique function to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

name your field name="myfield[]" then it will come to php in an array

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the answer above

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="myfield[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myfield[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myfield[]" value="3" />

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

If you vardump the $_POST variable from PHP, you will get the following output.

```
array(1) { ["myfield"]=>  array(2) { [0]=>  string(1) "1" [1]=>  string(1) "3" } }
```

In this example I selected value 1 and 3. The value of the checkbox should be the id.